# delete file operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, apt

I am using Ubuntu 16LTS and performed a regular upgrade with apt. The upgrade failed with `openssh-server` and apt complained it could not upgrade because it cannot make a backup of `/usr/sbin/sshd`

I removed `openssh-server` and tried to reinstall it. No luck and apt comes back with the same message. I remove `openssh-server` again.

When I try to manually change or remove `/usr/sbin/sshd` I get the message that "Operation is not permitted". I tried to remove the attribute `chattr -a -i /usr/sbin/sshd` but it keeps responding that the operation not permitted. An other annoying issue is that `lsattr` does not give back any info.

How can I force a delete or move of the `/usr/sbin/sshd` file?

Answer (score 0):

The following command will show you which process `lock` a specific file:

```
sudo lsof /usr/sbin/sshd
```

If the result of `lsof` will give you `sshd` service than you should stop the service before performing the upgrade.

Assuming the you tried to remove `sshd` while it is still running, you can try to stop `sshd` first.

Using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh stop
```

or

```
sudo service ssh stop
```

After the service is stopped, you can try to upgrade via `apt` or remove the folder manually.

Comment: When I run the lsof /usr/sbin/sshd command I do not get anything back. The sshd process is not running, so it could not lock the file.

Comment: @FreddeGoede - okay, so now the file is not locked. what happened when you try to execute the `apt` command (or move/delete the file)?

Comment: When I execute the apt command it says it cannot install openssh-server because it cannot make a backup of /usr/sbin/sshd

Comment: When I try to delete it, it says "Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. Apearently the lsattr and chattr files where damaged. Maybe I was hacked. When I replaced the two files with the correct version I could remove the -i flag and I could remove sshd.

Thanks for the help Yaron.